# deleting an object from an array of objects in java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

class Count {
    int count;
    String name;

    void SetCount(int c, String n) {
        this.count = c;
        this.name = n;
    }

    void Show() {
        System.out.print("Word= " + name);
        System.out.print(" Count= " + count);
        System.out.println();
    }
}

class Contains2 extends Count {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s = "Hello this program will repeat itself for this useless purpose and will not end until it repeats itself again and again and again so watch out";
        int i, c2, j;

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, " ");
        c2 = st.countTokens();

        String[] test = new String[c2];
        Count[] c = new Count[c2];

        for (i = 0; i < c2; i++) {
            c[i] = new Count();
        }

        i = 0;

        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String token = st.nextToken();

            test[i] = token;
            c[i].SetCount(0, test[i]);
            i++;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < c2; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
                if (c[i].name.equals(test[j]))
                    c[i].count += 1;
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < c2; i++) {
            c[i].Show();
        }
    }
}
```

so i made this small program to count the number every word was repeated in a paragraph. its working as planned but now i am getting duplicates of every word since i made separate objects for each and printing them all. so is there any way i could delete the duplicate words i mean deleting those objects based on their names. i can set them to null but it would still print them so i just wanna get rid of them or skip them somehow

Comment: I would use a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Comment: HashMap is perfect fit for your scenario, however you can set them to null and while showing only call show if its not null

Answer (score 0):

You cannot adjust the size of a array once it's created. You could only create a new array with a different size and copy the non-null elements.

You could also set elements to `null` and just ignore those elements for printing...

```
for (i = 0; i < c2; i++) {
    if (c[i] != null)
        c[i].Show();
}
```

An alternative would be using a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), which allows you to remove elements.

Alternatively a [`Map<String, Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) mapping from a word to the count could be used. In this case you don't even need the `Count` class:

```
String s = "Hello this program will repeat itself for this useless purpose and will not end until it repeats itself again and again and again so watch out";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, " ");

Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    map.merge(st.nextToken(), 1, Integer::sum);
}

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.print("Word= " + e.getKey());
    System.out.print(" Count= " + e.getValue());
    System.out.println();
}
```